# Haskell check if the regular expression r made up of the single symbol alphabet Σ = {a} defines language L(r) = a*

Tags: regex, haskell

I have got to write an algorithm programatically using haskell. The program takes a regular expression r made up of the unary alphabet Σ = {a} and check if the regular expression r defines the language L(r) = a^* (Kleene star). I am looking for any kind of tip. I know that I can translate any regular expression to the corresponding NFA then to the DFA and at the very end minimize DFA then compare, but is there any other way to achieve my goal? I am asking because it is clearly said that this is the unary alphabet, so I suppose that I have to use this information somehow to make this exercise much easier.

This is how my regular expression data type looks like

```
data Reg = Epsilon |          -- epsilon regex
           Literal Char |     -- a
           Or Reg Reg |       -- (a|a)
           Then Reg Reg |     -- (aa)
           Star Reg           -- (a)*
           deriving Eq
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to imagine a good shortcut for this. I would suggest following the approach you described in the question. For example, `a(aa)*a|(aa)*a|epsilon` covers all possibilities, but replacing each `aa` with `aaa` changes the result. Will you teach your program about factoring, to handle this?

Comment: @amalloy I'm not sure factoring even helps. Replace your first branch with `aa(aa*)` and all of a sudden there isn't even any factoring possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is another way. Every DFA for regular languages on the single-letter alphabet is a "lollipop"<sup>1</sup>: an initial string of nodes that each point to each other (some of which are marked as final and some not) followed by a loop of nodes (again, some of which are marked as final and some not). So instead of doing a full compilation pass, you can go directly to a DFA, where you simply store two `[Bool]` saying which nodes in the lead-in and in the loop are marked final (or perhaps two `[Integer]` giving the indices and two `Integer` giving the lengths may be easier, depending on your implementation plans). You don't need to ensure the compiled version is minimal; it's easy enough to check that all the `Bool`s are `True`. The base cases for `Epsilon` and `Literal` are pretty straightforward, and with a bit of work and thought you should be able to work out how to implement the combining functions for "or", "then", and "star" (hint: think about gcd's and stuff).

<sup>1</sup> You should try to prove this before you begin implementing, so you can be sure you believe me.

Edit 1: Hm, while on my afternoon walk today, I realized the idea I had in mind for "then" (and therefore "star") doesn't work. I'm not giving up on this idea (and deleting this answer) yet, but those operations may be trickier than I gave them credit for at first. This approach definitely isn't for the faint of heart!

Edit 2: Okay, I believe now that I have access to pencil and paper I've worked out how to do concatenation and iteration. Iteration is actually easier than concatenation. I'll give a hint for each -- though I have no idea whether the hint is a good one or not!

Suppose your two lollipops have a length `m` lead-in and a length `n` loop for the first one, and `m'`/`n'` for the second one. Then:

1. For iteration of the first lollipop, there's a fairly mechanical/simple way to produce a lollipop with a `2*m + 2*n`-long lead-in and `n`-long loop.
2. For concatenation, you can produce a lollipop with `m + n + m' + lcm(n, n')`-long lead-in and `n`-long loop (yes, that short!).